# NopCommerce 3.8 Custom Plugin View Tabs

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, nopcommerce

Ive followed the Tutorial for creating a custom plugin from [Plural site tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/nopcommerce-plugin-development/table-of-contents)

However as of now it is a little out of date with Nop version 3.8.

Ive followed the tutorial and made one change (the admin menu).

Im about to create the "CreateUpdatePromoSlider.cshtml" but im hit with an issue.

```
<li @Html.RenderSelectedTabIndex(0, GetSelectedTabIndex())>Slider</li>
```

Seems "@Html" doesnt contain a definition for "RenderSelectedTabIndex" anymore.

Im guessing it was changed in 3.8, does any one know the fix for this in relation to the tutorial?

you can assume that the rest of the code folows the tutoiral exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `@Html.RenderBootstrapTabHeader` and `@Html.RenderBootstrapTabContent` methods instead of `@Html.RenderSelectedTabIndex`. They are now used in nopCommerce admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific in syntax and how to use below is the code i created to replace the tutorial code.

```
<div class="content">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="slider-edit" class="nav-tabs-custom">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            @Html.RenderBootstrapTabHeader("Slider", @T("Slider"), true)
            @Html.RenderBootstrapTabHeader("Images", @T("Images"))
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            @Html.RenderBootstrapTabContent("Slider", Sliders(), true)
            @Html.RenderBootstrapTabContent("Images", Images(), false)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Additional to this all code that was once "tabled" can now be changed to divs and its classes to bootstrap.